# Is there a way not to type the "http(s)://" prefix in UIWebview for user to go to a website?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have the following lines of code used to let user type in the URL address of a website and present the website within the app:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.myView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.myText.text]]];
    [self.myText resignFirstResponder];
}
```

But it turns out to be that you have to type `http://` every time you type in the URL address, otherwise it will not work, is there a way for me not to do that? thanks

Comment: If there's no `@"http://"` at the start of `self.myText.text`, stick it on the front before you form the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add it if it's not there:

```
NSString* fullyQualifiedURL = [@"http://" stringByAppendingString:self.myText.text];
```

Comment: Ideally the webview would automatically redirect to the https url if the website supports it (the same way your browser redirects `http://facebook.com` to `https://facebook.com`) - I can't verify this though